# Рекуррентное вычисление суммы

Tags: c

> Вычислить бесконечную сумму с заданной точностью, используя рекуррентные зависимости.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    float f, s, x;
    int n;
    do {
        printf("x=");
        scanf("%f", &x);
    } while (x <= -1 || x >= 1);
    for (s = 0, f = (-1) * pow(x, 2) / n, n = 1; fabs(f) > 1E-4; n++) ;
    {
        s += f;
        f *= (-1) * pow(x, 2) / n;
    }
    printf("s=%f\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

Не могу найти ошибку, после компиляции ввожу значения x и мне должно вывести значение s, но почему-то опять появляется введение значения x.

Comment: Это код такой? И как его читать? Переведите его в НАСТОЯЩИЙ код, там кнопка с надписью 101010 есть для этого...

Comment: un-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'n' is being used without being initialized.

Comment: сначала n = 1, затем уже f = (-1) * pow(x, 2) / n. Лучше в начале сразу писать int n=1;

Comment: Все, спасибо, заработала родимая:

 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <math.h>
 int main(void)
 {
  float f, s, x;
  int n = 1;
  do {
   printf("x=");
   scanf("%f", &x);
  } while (x <= -1.0 && x >= 1.0);
  for (s = 0, n = 1, f = (-1) * pow(x, 2) / n; fabs(f) > 1E-4; n++) {
   s += f;
   f *= (-1) * pow(x, 2) / n;
  }
  printf("s=%f\n", s);
  return 0;
 }

Answer (score 3):

1) После for(...) точка с запятой не ставится.

2) Если x типа float, то надо писать while (x <= -1.0 || x >= 1.0);

3) Значит, х должно быть от -1.0 до 1.0, иначе он просто зацикливается и повторяет ввод данных... Лучше писать

```
while(true){
   ...
   if(x>=-1.0&&x<=1.0)
break;}
```

4) Я уже молчу за неинициализированную перед применением переменную n...